# Keycloak behind a Load Balancer with SSL gives a "Mixed Content" error

Tags: keycloak, gcp-load-balancer

I have set up Keycloak (docker container) on the GCP Compute Engine (VM). After setting the `sslRequired=none`, I'm able to access Keycloak over a public IP (e.g. http://33.44.55.66:8080) and manage the realm.

I have configured the GCP CLassic (HTTPS) Load Balancer and added two front-ends as described below. The Load Balancer forwards the request to the Keycloak instance on the VM.

- HTTP: http://55.44.33.22/keycloak
- HTTPS: https://my-domain.com/keycloak

In the browser, the HTTP URL works fine and I'm able to login to Keycloak and manage the realm. However, for the HTTPS URL, I get the below error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain.com/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://my-domain.com/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=gyc8p'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**Note:** I tried [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1000573/614502) suggestion, but it didn't work

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: `sslRequired=none` is insecure. Keycloak should be available only via https protocol, so make sure you have configured proper ssl offloading.

Comment: @JanGaraj, I get the same error even when `sslRequired=ALL` or `sslRequired=EXTERNAL`. Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: SSL offloading must be configured properly, so Keycloak container with `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` and LB with proper request header X-Forwarded-* configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068266/keycloak-docker-behind-loadbalancer-with-https-fails

Comment: @JanGaraj, this worked for me. You may post this as an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never expose Keycloak on plain http protocol. Keyclok admin console itself is secured via OIDC protocol and OIDC requires to use https protocol. So default `sslRequired=EXTERNAL` is safe and smart configuration option from the vendor.

SSL offloading must be configured properly:

- Keycloak container with `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`
- loadbalancer/reverse proxy (nginx, GCP Classic Load Balancer, AWS ALB, ...) with proper request header `X-Forwarded-*` configuration, so Keycloak container will know correct protocol, domain which is used for the users

Comment: GCP Classic Load balancer preserves the `X-Forwarded-*` headers in the request. This is documented in the Load Balancer support pages.